# Flume morphline interceptor: For Data cleaning

Tags: flume, morphline

I have a simple structured input coming real time.
But it has garbage also in the values like in some place '@' or Hexadecimal characters are there.

How can i use morphline flume interceptor to clean the data?

My sink here will be hbase.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use Morphline over flume for your requirements. 
In general, Morphline offers some basic functions for parsing and transforming data. On top of that, you can build your own Morphline Command and then use your custom method in your morphlines config.